# What graphics card is faster than i7

Tags: rendering, gpu, performance

I have a 5th generation MSI BOARD, H77MA-G43 with 16 Gig ram and CPU: i7 3770|3.4GHz.
I render within cycles, the render time of the i7 CPU is 5 times faster than the GeForce Gtx 1050 ti
What graphics card will be faster than the i7?

Comment: The [Blender Open Data](https://opendata.blender.org/) website should answer your question.

Comment: Perhaps the i9?

Comment: Also make sure that the tile size is set appropriately, your GPU should be faster than your CPU.